# java,Xml parsing

Tags: java, xml

I want to parse like this xml file in java.
I know using SAX or DOM, we can parse XML file.
But as per my knowledge if xml is like this

```
<XML><FORM><ITEM>Name</ITEM> <ITEM>Area</ITEM> <ITEM>ZipCode</ITEM> </FORM></XML>
```

we can parse it.

How can i get other properties like label, title,type. as in this XML file.
How to do that?
Please help me!!!

```
<XML><FORM TITLE="Search" View="1"><ITEM Label="Name" Type="Alpha" maxWidth="25"ID="name" Align="LEFT"></ITEM> <ITEM Label="Area " Type="AlphaNumeric" maxWidth="20" ID="area" Align="LEFT"></ITEM> <ITEM Label="Zip Code" Type="Numeric" maxWidth="10" ID="zip" Align="LEFT"></ITEM><ITEM Label="Search within radius of" Type="Radio" maxWidth="20" ID="ID" Align=" CENTER"><LIST_VALUES><ID="20" VALUE="20 kms"<ID="50" VALUE="50 kms"> <ID="100" VALUE="20 kms"></LIST_VALUES></ITEM></FORM><XML>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Any civilized XML parser (whether based on SAX, DOM, or whatever) will allow you to access attributes (what you call "other properties") - Anyway I put an exemple using DOM in my answer below

Comment: you can go [here](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html) and start reading a bit..

Answer (score 0):

TITLE, Label, etc are **ATTRIBUTES** of the various XML Nodes.  Depending on the exact api you're using you'd generally find a method named something like `getAttribute(String name)` which would allow you to retrieve the content of the particular attribute.

I remember JDOM allowing you to call getAttribute(..) on an instance of an Element, which mapped to an XML node

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple using DOM, once you have your ITEM element (for instance):

```
String labelValue= itemElement.getAttribute("Label");
```